c++-mode and c++-ts-mode not working
I'm using emacs-plus and I had treesitter priorly installed. Other modes like python-ts-mode work fine. However, c++-ts-mode is void and does not exist as a variable. In addition, when I call c++-mode interactively, it is not available (but it is set as the major-mode in *.cpp buffers).
Has anyone experienced this issue and knows of a fix?

Use C-h f to check the defintion. Paste something from the resulting buffer into your question.

The functions are void, as I mentioned @db48x. The definition does not exist.

I get c++-ts-mode is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in ‘c-ts-mode.el’ for the first and c++-mode is an autoloaded interactive subr-native-elisp in ‘cc-mode.el’. for the second. So something is screwy with your setup. What version of Emacs are you running?

Yea I understand @NickD . There are other issues as well with my set-up that occur sporadically, but c++-ts-mode not existing and c++-mode not being available interactively are the two most prominent. It's on a M1 Pro Macbook.

These two should be available with recent Emacs (at least 29.3 and later). If you are running such a recent version, then you have to fix your setup. If you are running an older version, you might need to upgrade. So check your version with M-x emacs-version and add it to your question.

I am running that version @NickD, as mentioned -- I am using emacs-plus. I installed it this past week.

I have no idea what emacs-plus means.

It's just a homebrew formula for emacs @NickD

In this case it would be to know your settings for c++-ts-mode. Please note the c++-mode (pertaining to cc-mode) and c++-ts-mode are two different modes, you must choose one or the other and do not mix them. If you show your settings, I can comment more or even an answer (I am using emacs-plus with c++ts-mode and treesit (built-in in 29.x)).

@Ian c++-ts-mode is a void variable for me, and c++-mode doesn't show up when called interactively. My settings were simply following Mastering Emacs with a bare skeleton for setting up the treesit modes.

Do not use Mastering...

c++-ts-mode is supposed to be a function, not a variable. They’re not the same thing. Use C-h f to find out about the definition of a function. If it really is undefined, then you have bigger problems that you need to solve than just configuring a mode. But you’re using a mac and I have no idea what the best way to install Emacs on a mac is.

I suggest to use this package
to solve major problems with treesit.
If your grammars are correctly installed go further, if not, follow the
indications on that page.
If you have treesitter, it will be a good idea to remove it, since the package
above make use of  built-in treesit.
What you need to add further is the below snippet, to reckognize the file
types and start the c++-ts-mode hook:
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\(\\.ii\\|\\.\\(CC?\\|HH?\\)\\|\\.[ch]\\(pp\\|xx\\|\\+\\+\\)\\|\\.\\(cc\\|hh\\)\\)\\'"
               . c++-ts-mode))
;; optional
(add-hook 'c++-ts-mode-hook 'lsp-deferred)
(add-hook 'c++-ts-mode-hook #'highlight-indent-guides-mode)

Then open a .cpp file and verify the major mode with C-h m.
